# How to obtain a close form/fast expression for this integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function, integration-by-parts, approximate-integration

I have the following integral:

$$ I_p = \int_0^1 x^{p-1}(ax + b) e ^{-(ax + b)^2/N}dx$$

where

$$ \{x,a,b\} \in (-\infty,\infty), \; N \in (0,\infty), \; p \in \mathbb Z, p \geq 1 . $$

I want to find a stable formula for computation of $J_p$.

(a) I am able to obtain a recursion using the integration by parts formula between $J_p, J_{p-1}$ and $J_{p-2}$, but there is $a$ in the denominator which can take small values close to zero and hence the recursion blows up.

(b) I do not want to do it numerically as it is not as efficient.

I want to know if this integral can be expression as some function which can be computed efficiently?

1) Recursion:

Now, $$I_p = a J_p + b J_{p-1}$$

such that

$$ J_p = \int_0^1 x^{p} e ^{-(ax + b)^2/N}dx$$

And we can get a recursion on the above integral as:

$$J_{p+1} = \frac{Np}{2a^2} J_{p-1} - \frac{b}{a} J_p - \frac{N}{2a^2} e^{-(a+b)^2/N}$$

I have the closed form expressions for $J_0$ and $J_1$ in terms of *erf* or normal cdf. The problem is that $a$ and its powers are in denominator, causing recursion to be unstable.

Comment: Could you post the recursion ?

Comment: What is $N$? Also $0 \le x \le 1$.

Comment: Is $p$ an integer or is it real?

Comment: Recursion posted. @jim $x$ is real, but anyway the domain of integration is from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: If $a=0$, we obtain $\int_0^1 x^{p-1}be^{-b^2/N}\,dx=\frac{b}{p}e^{-b^2/N}$. If $a\neq 0$, Mathematica is capable of computing the first few $p$ explicitly; but it doesn't seem able to do $p\geq 1$ generally, and I don't see the closed-form pattern for these small cases.

Comment: Yes. I am aware of the above case $a=0$, but in general, is it possible to obtain a more stable recursion? In reality, $a$ is never zero, but very very small.

Comment: Minor typo: In your recursion formula $p = k$?

Comment: Could you show how you got your recursion formula? I would have expected to have seen $J_k$ in terms of $J_{k-1}, J_{k-2}$ and $J_{k-3}$. (May be easier to scan in).

Comment: @jim it is simple integration by parts and then rearranging to get $J_{p+1}$ on the other side. This  of-course assumes $x^{p-1}$ as second function in integration by parts. Thnx for poiting out the typo.

Comment: Since your constants are apparently variable in the problems of interest to you, I'd suggest that you change variables to $y=\frac{ax+b}{N^{1/2}}$ so that the dependence on the parameters can be factored into the algebraic part. In particular this will let you factor some parameter aggregates out of the problem altogether, which should be helpful.

Comment: If you absorb the $N$ into the $a, b$ giving $\alpha = \frac{a}{\sqrt{N}}, \beta = \frac{b}{\sqrt{N}}$ the integral can be written $\sqrt{N}$ $I_p$ with$I_p = \int_0^1 x^{p-1}(\alpha x + \beta) e ^{-(\alpha x + \beta)^2}dx$ and $I_p$ is independent of $N$.

Comment: I only ask because I seem to get the recurrence relation $2 \alpha^3 I_p = I_{p-3} - C - 2\alpha^2 \beta I_{p-1} - \alpha \beta I_{p-2}$ with $C = (\alpha + \beta)e^{-(\alpha + \beta)^2}$.

Comment: @jim You are correct with your recursion. I am sorry I did not elaborate much on what the recursion meant. I have included the details. I want to obtain $J_p$ and $J_{p-1}$ in  a stable manner.

Answer (score 1):

If
$J_{p+1} 
= \frac{Np}{2a^2} J_{p-1} - \frac{b}{a} J_p - \frac{N}{2a^2} e^{-(a+b)^2/N}
$,
then
multuplying by
$a^{p+1}$,
$a^{p+1}J_{p+1} 
= \frac{Np}{2} a^{p-1}J_{p-1} - a^p J_p - \frac{N}{2}a^{p-1} e^{-(a+b)^2/N}
$.

If we let
$K_p
= a^p J_p
$,
this becomes
$K_{p+1} 
= \frac{Np}{2} K_{p-1} - K_p - \frac{N}{2}a^{p-1} e^{-(a+b)^2/N}
$.

This looks like it 
might be more stable.

Comment: @cohen  This looks good. Let me work out and come back. I am happy that  now we only need to divide once by $a^{p+1}$ in the end to obtain the quantities.

Comment: @cohen, unfortunately, The expression for $J_0$ has an $a$ in the denominator and is the base case. Also, In the end I have to divide by $a^{p+1}$, which creates a problem while obtaining the final quantity. Numerically, this is still a problem. Even if I define $K_p = a^{p+1} J_p$, the problem of dividing by $a^{p+1}$ in the end is troublesome.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$\int_0^1x^{p-1}(ax+b)e^{-\frac{(ax+b)^2}{N}}~dx$

$=\int_\frac{b}{a}^{\frac{b}{a}+1}ax\left(x-\dfrac{b}{a}\right)^{p-1}e^{-\frac{a^2x^2}{N}}~dx$

$=\int_\frac{b}{a}^{\frac{b}{a}+1}\sum\limits_{n=1}^p\dfrac{C_{n-1}^{p-1}(-1)^{p-n}b^{p-n}x^ne^{-\frac{a^2x^2}{N}}}{a^{p-n-1}}~dx$

$=\int_\frac{b}{a}^{\frac{b}{a}+1}\sum\limits_{n=1}^p\dfrac{(-1)^{p-n}(p-1)!b^{p-n}x^ne^{-\frac{a^2x^2}{N}}}{(n-1)!(p-n)!a^{p-n-1}}~dx$

Comment: I am unable to see how it helps....